# Python - Permutation/Combination column-wise

Tags: python, python-2.7, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

I have a list

```
mylist = [
    ['f', 'l', 'a', 'd', 'l', 'f', 'k'], 
    ['g', 'm', 'b', 'b', 'k', 'g', 'l'], 
    ['h', 'n', 'c', 'a', 'm', 'j', 'o'], 
    ['i', 'o', 'd', 'c', 'n', 'i', 'm'],
    ['j', 'p', 'e', 'e', 'o', 'h', 'n'], 
]
```

I want do permutation/combination column-wise, such the elements of the column are restricted to that column i.e., f,g,h,i,j remain in Column 1, l,m,n,o,p remain in Column 2 and so on, in the results of permutation/combination. How can this be achieved in Python 2.7?

Answer (score 1):

You could [use `zip(*mylist)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to list the "columns" of `mylist`. Then use [the `*` operator](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/) (again) to unpack those lists as arguments to `IT.product` or `IT.combinations`. For example,

```
import itertools as IT
list(IT.product(*zip(*mylist)))
```

yields

```
[('f', 'l', 'a', 'd', 'l', 'f', 'k'),
 ('f', 'l', 'a', 'd', 'l', 'f', 'l'),
 ('f', 'l', 'a', 'd', 'l', 'f', 'o'),
 ('f', 'l', 'a', 'd', 'l', 'f', 'm'),
 ...]
```